# checking if a row n mysql is already exists and if exists then display different echo

Tags: php, mysql, function, session

I am trying to develop an e-commerce website where I will put some products.Customers can put products in "wishlist" they like, at the same time the button should be changed to 'collected' from 'collect' sooner they click on it . My code so far :

**in dbconnect.php**

```
function if_already_collected($collector_id){
    $db_conn=getConnection();
    mysqli_set_charset($db_conn,'utf8');

    if(!$db_conn)return false;


    $sql="SELECT collected_id from collection where collector_id=$collector_id";


    $result=$db_conn->query($sql);
    $db_conn->close();
    return $result->num_rows > 0;
}
```

**in member_profile.php**

```
<?php 
 include_once("dbconnection.php");
  if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
   }
 /*USER INFO : GETTING ID*/
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];      
$pword = $_SESSION['password'];
$members = display_member_info($uname, $pword);   
 while($member = $members->fetch_assoc()) :
    $collector_id=$member['id'];
endwhile ; 
?>

<div class="member_card">


    <div class="member">    
        <?php $mems= 
     serach_members($query_name,$query_elaka,$query_division,$query_district,$query_thana); ?>

            <?php while ($mem= $mems->fetch_assoc()) : ?>

     <?php if (if_already_collected($collector_id)) { ?>
                       <table>
                         <tr>
                        <td><a href="member_collect.php?get_id_cll=<?php echo $mem['id']; ?> && 
                        get_name_cll=<?php echo $mem['full_name']; ?>">Collect</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }else{  ?>

                       <tr>
                         <td>Collected</td>
                      </tr>
                   </table>
                    <?php } ?>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>

             </div>
```

these code yields "collect" for all products even if i click on 'collect' (stored in database as well ) and yield 'collected' for all products even if i don't click on any when i replace the conditional statement by this :

```
<?php if (!if_already_collected($collector_id)) { ?>
```

Comment: `serach_members()` < appears to be misspelled and isn't shown as to what that function does and bears the same name.

Comment: You're using the same `$collector_id` every time through the loop, so the result will always be the same.

Comment: The function doesn't tell if a specific item is in the wishlist, just whether that user has a wishlist.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank for addressing this, but i misspelled in both side lol

Comment: @Barmar what command should I use instead, can you kindly write down the full condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to check whether `$mem['id']` is in the user's collection. Currently it just checks whether the user has anything in their collection, not that specific item.

```
function if_already_collected($collector_id, $collected_id){
    $db_conn=getConnection();
    mysqli_set_charset($db_conn,'utf8');

    if(!$db_conn)return false;

    $sql="SELECT 1 from collection where collector_id = ? and collected_id = ?";
    $stmt = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $collector_id, $collected_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ignore);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    $db_conn->close();
    return $row;
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
     <?php if (if_already_collected($collector_id, $mem['id'])) { ?>
```

I've also shown how to convert the code to use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables, to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: thank you brother , I am checking your code - I need to rearrange them so need some time

Comment: your code worked perfectly sir ! thanks a lot for your help